# Как заблокировать любые переходы по ссылке в определенном контейнере?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я загружаю cURL'ом чужой сайт, и вывожу его (полностью весь сайт) внутри своего домена.

Для общего понимая поясню: вверху размещена моя шапка сайт. потом полностью весь чужой сайт. потом мой футер. Получается что-то типа:

```
<div class="my_header>...</div>
    <div class="site_donor">.......</div>
<div class="my_footer>...</div>
```

Я хочу сделать чтобы любой клик по ссылке внутри блока **site_donor** перехватывался бы, и не происходил переход на ссылку.

Тут по сути просто:

```
$(".site_donor").on('click', 'a', function() { ... });
```

Но у некоторых сайтов-доноров клик по ссылке перехватывает их же JavaScript, и каким-то образом делает перенаправление куда им нужно.

Как обойти это? Хотелось бы чтобы в блоке **site_donor** любые скрипты которые отвечают за перенаправление были не активны.

Как например это сделано у яндекс или гугл переводчика сайтов...

Буду благодарен за информацию!

Comment: как на счет `$(".site_donor a").off('click');` или `$(".site_donor a").unbind('click');` прежде чем добавлять свой обработчик?

Comment: попробовал: **$(".site_donor").unbind('click', function() {** не помогло

Comment: Нужно указывать handler для [unbind](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9), а не анонимную функцию.

Comment: Почему не через css - pointer-events:none?

Comment: @Kirill конечно сработало. но а как теперь мне ловить события клика на ссылку?

Answer (score 0):

```
[... document.links].forEach (a => a.style ['pointer-events'] = 'none')
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно используя `e.preventDefault()` и `$(".site_donor a").unbind('click');`:

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $(".site_donor a").unbind("click");  // <<< выключаем обработку нажатий в site_donor
  $(".site_donor a").click('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // <<< предотвращаем переход по ссылке
    
    alert($(this).text() + " my handler");
    
    // ... do smth
  });  
});
```

```css
.my_header, .my_footer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.site_donor {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my_header">header</div>
    <div class="site_donor">
      <div class="content">
        <a href="#">link 1</a>
        <a href="https://google.com">link 2</a>
      </div>
      
      <script type="text/javascript">
        /*
          внутренние обработчики
        */
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".content a").on("click", function() {
            alert($(this).text() + " site_donor");
          });
        });
      </script>
      
    </div>
<div class="my_footer"></div>
```

Comment: не срабатывает. пробую вот на этом сайте-доноре, в желтой горизонтальной области меню - mytoys.de

Comment: может там не на клик обработчики или ваш скрипт вызывается до выполнения скриптов `.site_donor`?

Comment: да, мой скрипт вызывается до выполнения скриптов донора. сейчас сделаю чтобы он вызывался после. и отпишусь

Comment: мой скрипт по прежднему вызывается в <head> до загрузки страницы, но я добавил вот так: **$(window).on('load', function () { $(".site_donor a").unbind("click"); });** но не помогает...

Comment: А если в `site_donor` есть скрипты, которые в аналогичном событии делают бинд, но вызывается оно позже? При вызове `unbind` будет нечего анбиндить. Попробуй сделать `unbind` не при `load`, а по нажатию какой-то элемент где-то в шапке или футере. Если сработает, то проблема в порядке выполнения скриптов. Если же нет, то смотри внимательно, какие конкретно события обрабатываются.

Comment: тогда полагаю нужно как-то отследить момент создания события я отменить это событие. это возможно?